# Based on Input value in FormBuilder array type value control not creating

Tags: javascript, html, angular, formgroups

I have json object that contains `Application` name property and it's value array of object.
When creating control using `FormBuilder` Application type is Object instead of array of values.

here is the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ig9rdm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

FormControl [image]

How to get value as array in contorl for the `Application` property?

Comment: Arrays are inherently objects in JavaScript that's why it is showing its type as Object.

Comment: yes @ammadkh , why does value is missing in contorl? is array type value not possible?

Comment: In angular we use FormControlArray for this type of value

Answer (score 1):

declare it as `FormArray` Control like the following :

```
ChidlrenForm = this.fb.group({
  entityName: ['', Validators.required],
  entityType: [''],
 applications: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.control('')
      ])
});
```

you can see the applications in the `formBuilder`  declared as applications

Comment: @r08 what did you mean by "idea ... +v1 ??"

Comment: Might be it's high level but for me it's worked like hint,not complete answered,so i given one up vote

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code to create FormArray and FormControl from json.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder){

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.createConrol()
  }
  createConrol(){
    let listOfChildren =[
      {
        "EntityName": "",
        "EntityType": "Tenant",
        "Application": [
          {
            "Value": "Test1",
            "EntityName": "Test1"
          },
          {
            "Value": "Test2",
            "EntityName": "Test2"
          }
        ],
        "EntityId": "339fff35-643b-482f-aff9-69607e80024d"
      }
    ];
   
    const group = this.formBuilder.group({});
 
    listOfChildren.forEach(obj => {
          let control = this.createFormArrayAndObjectControl(obj)  
          group.addControl(obj.EntityId, control)
      });
  }

  createFormArrayAndObjectControl(obj){
    const group = this.formBuilder.group({});
    for(const key in obj){
      if(Array.isArray(obj[key])){
        let formArrayControl  = this.formBuilder.array([]);
        for(var innerObj of obj[key]){
          let control = this.createControl(innerObj);
          formArrayControl.push(control);
        }
        group.addControl(key,formArrayControl);
      }
      else {
        group.addControl(key,this.createControl(obj[key]));
      }          
    }
    return group; 
  }

  createControl(value){
    return this.formBuilder.control(value,{ updateOn: "blur" })
  }
}
```